# Having trouble getting the modified rotational angle of fabic.js object retaliative to is original angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, rotation, fabricjs

Having trouble getting the modified rotational angle of fabic.js object retaliative to is original angle/position.

I'm using .getAngle(), If the object is rotated more than 360 degrees or rotated back and forth I'm having trouble converting this back to an angle in degrees relative to it original position/rotation.

```js
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

     //global canvas setting 
    canvas.selection = false;
    canvas.setDimensions({
      width: 500,
      height: 310
    });
     //Canvas Objets 
     // create a rectangle with angle=45
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      lockUniScaling: true,
      centeredRotation: true
    });

    canvas.add(rect);

     //Object modification event    
    canvas.on('object:modified', function(e) {
      var activeObject = e.target;
      document.getElementById('result').value = activeObject.getAngle();
    });
```

I've setup a fiddle showing the default output http://jsfiddle.net/1db5g7us/

I'm assuming in need to do some calculation on the result, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this one, all i needed to do was use the modulus operator to get the rotation relative to its original position rather than the total rotated angle.

```
            activeObject = activeObject%360;
```

update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1db5g7us/